# Should We Close Connection to Sql Server Database Before Using Another Query?

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2008

when we want to connect  to database from visual studio should we always check(before using another query) that if our connection is open,close it and again open it??

```
 if(connection is open){
  close connection;
   }  
  open connection for another use;
```

Comment: Why exactly would you want to close a connection just to have to open it again?

Comment: The practice is actually to close the connection when you are "Done" with it to leave a smaller footprint and reduce memory leaks.  Closing the connection before executing another implies either 1) you're not done, 2) Previous areas of the application in which the user "Could have been done" didn't clean up.

Comment: some people said its better to close and open it again,so should we do this

Comment: @xQbert:can you explain me about number 2??thanks

Comment: #2) above: The point here is the cleanup should be done in the code that originally created and used the connection.  if I have a function that makes multiple calls to the database opening and closing within that function is not necessary it's overhead that detracts from performance. However,  I should ensure that I close it and destroy the connection object before my function ends; even if my function results in an error, the connection object needs to be destroyed. IF I don't do this I'm hoping garbage collection cleans up the mess I leave; which can result in the memory leak I mentioned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're using .NET, you should generally open and close the connection for each logical operation. If you're doing multiple queries in the same code path (i.e. you *know* you're about to do another query) then it makes sense to leave the connection open, but I wouldn't leave it open "just in case".

Bear in mind that the connection pooling in .NET makes it reasonably cheap to "open a connection" as the network connection will still be up anyway. Typically you'd use something like:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(...))
{
    connection.Open();
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(connection, sql))
    {
        // Execute the command etc
    }
}
```

The `using` statement will "close the connection" (read: return it to the connection pool) automatically when you're done.

Keeping each query (or set of queries) logically separate means it's harder to end up with race conditions, threading issues etc. I *wouldn't* recommend keeping a connection as a global variable or anything like that.

Of course, if you're using something like LINQ to SQL the connection handling is likely to be mostly done for you.

Comment: thanks for your complete answer,so if i use "using"(like your code),this doesnt need to close and open it again for each query??(i want to know i understood your answer well or not)

Comment: @arash: It will close it, but that really only means returning it to the connection pool.

Answer (score 1):

It depends, but in most cases - the answer is **no**.

You should close the connection only if there is a relatively long time between queries.

And I **personally** think, that the connection should be closed if the queries are not connected semantically - ie. the queries from different workflows or other logically complete pieces.

**Especially** for your case - if you use the connection pooling - it does not matter - will you close the connection or not,

**BUT**

in case of improper use of transactions or setting session state `SET` statement, which can interfere with the future queries - then I recommend to close the connection and reopen it - just to be sure, that you committed or rolled back all the forgotten transactions and session state was reset to its defaults